# CSS flex-start items doesn't get centered

Tags: html, css

So i have this flex container with justify-content: flex-start and i want to center the items inside it.

EDIT:for comparison i want it to be like youtube homepage video recommendations.

Here is my code i don't understand why it's not working: (it looks like centered but it's not there is a width left out from child container, please use dev tools and hover over the child container you'll see it)

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:500px
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
  item
</div><div class="item">
  item
</div><div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
      item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is what i want:(i know it's not centered but the point is i want flex-start with margin 0 auto, hope it makes sense)

```css
.parent {
  width: "100%";
  margin-left: 15%;
  max-width:500px
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
  item
</div><div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
  item
</div><div class="item">
  item
</div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
      item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for answering

Comment: If you make `margin: auto;` for `.parent`, will you get the desired result?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov no still same thing

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the desired result. Those. how exactly do you want to center?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov just like the second snippet, i don't know how to center it.

Comment: Sorry friend, I don't understand what result you need. Hope the other person understands you.

Comment: I suspect that you _don't_ want flex start, but you want something to do with how the boxes wrap. What you describe is centered.

Comment: @isherwood no it's not centered please see the updated post again i used different item size to show it better

Comment: It won't center because your parent has a max-width of 500, each of your item is 125px wide + 5px on each side which makes them 135px wide in total, since 135px x 4 is greater than 500 so the last box wraps and the entire thing does not center because your flex container is using flex-start. You need to make sure your container and item width add up correctly to achieve the layout you want

Comment: @Huangism oh that makes sense then the problem is with box wrap it adds extra width before wrapping  you can see it if you use the dev tools. is there  any way to remove that extra width when wrapping?

Comment: Why `flex-start` and not  `center` ?

Comment: @AlandSleman see my answer, is there a reason why you don't want to use justify-content: center?

Comment: @Huangism i don't want use justify-content: center because if the row wraps the second row items will get centered instead of being placed at left,for example with 6 items first 4 items will be at first row last 2 at second row but centered instead of left. hope it makes sense

Comment: @AlandSleman if your container and margins are setup correctly, you could put margin-right: auto on the last flex item and it will align it to the left but then again, if your container/item/margin are setup correctly you might as well not use justify-content center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS grid job

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.child {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,125px); /* define the width here */
  grid-gap:5px; /* this is your margin */
  justify-content:center; /* center everything */
}

.item {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  height: 100px; /* you only need to define the height, you can also do it with grid-auto-rows:100px */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Note for me: I remember a similar question but not able to find it. Try to look for it later]

Answer (score 1):

As my comment says

It won't center because your parent has a max-width of 500, each of your item is 125px wide + 5px on each side which makes them 135px wide in total, since 135px x 4 is greater than 500 so the last box wraps and the entire thing does not center because your flex container is using flex-start. You need to make sure your container and item width add up correctly to achieve the layout you want

I changed the item width to 115px so 4 boxes adds up correctly to 500 without adjusting your current margin. You could also adjust your container width or you can adjust your margin. As long as the math works out it will look center beyond 500px wide

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:500px
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
  item
</div><div class="item">
  item
</div><div class="item">
      item
    </div><div class="item">
      item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is i don't know how many items are there and the when there is bigger and smaller screen sizes this method will be irrelevant

Comment: if you want to go with your current approach then you will need to setup fixed width content container and item width for each box then once the screen size is smaller than your content container, the number needs to change(media query). from a top level, you are creating a grid system. As far as the original question goes, the above answer explains and answers it.

Comment: so if i use grid system can i achieve it without media queries?

Comment: for comparison i want it to be like youtube homepage video recommendations.

Comment: There are existing grid systems out there like bootstrap, you could define a grid system with percentage width and avoid media queries but it will most likely not work that well across all sizes/devices. I don't know any website that is responsive and not use media queries. Media queries is part of css and should be used

Comment: ahh....i didn't want to use media queries because there is alot of work todo for each screen size, anyway thank you so much  for your time

Comment: It's not possible to avoid media queries if you want the site to look good on all sizes. You can most likely get away with 4-5 breakpoints in total. If you had a website where all elements just stack on top of each other, maybe then you can not use media queries but then again, maybe some font size needs to change when the screen is bigger or smaller.

Answer (score -1):

### to center a div using flex:

```css
.parent , body {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    width:100%;
}
```

personally, I don't use `margin: 0 auto;` trick because it doesn't work well for me.

I hope I answered your question.